# Как скачивать картинку из firebase storage?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-android

Не получается скачать картинку в память и загрузить в ImageView. Помогите пожалуйста,а то совсем запутался. Каждый раз приложение вылетает , Вот Код:

```
Image_kyrs = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://*******.appspot.com");

StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("scoin.png");

final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
gsReference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        Image_kyrs.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Картинка скачалась!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Ошибка!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

Вот такая ошибка:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
```

Разрешения вроде прописал:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

В firebase читать без авторизация тоже разрешено:

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
allow read, write;
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо , я уже сам разобрался,использовал библиотеку Picasso. Там всё проще) Вот код если вдруг кому пригодиться:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://ВАШ БАКЕТ.appspot.com");

// создаем ссылку на файл по адресу scoin.png
// вызываем getDownloadUrl() и устанавливаем слушатель успеха,
// который срабатывает в случае успеха процесса скачивания
storageRef.child("ВАША КАРТИНКА В FIREBASE.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

        Picasso.with(Chart.this).load(uri)
                .into(ImageView);  //ВАШ IMAGEVIEW,без id работать не будет
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Ошибка!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

**Подключение библиотеки:**

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

**И разрешение на интернет:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```